# How to omit tags in body field?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to search "Pop" keyword within the body which is as follows:

`$haystack = <p class="pop">This is PopStation<a href="/search/popstation">Test</a></p>`

Now `$needle` is my search variable i.e `$needle = 'pop'`

`preg_match_all("/$needle+/i", $haystack, $matches);`

Now I am passing the `$needle` in `preg_match_all` function which should search for `pop`. The above preg match does it but it search the pop keyword in tags also which I dont want. It should omit the tags section and search in text only.

Can anyone please help me out to write `preg_match_all` condition to omit tags.

Comment: [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) may help you.

Comment: Exactly what you wanted, only text or some thing else ?

Comment: If only text use `strip_tags`

Comment: So how you exactly want?

Comment: Yes I tried using strip tags, but it removes all the tags permanently. when I am searching the keyoword in body It should not take tags in cosideration. 


For example: <a href="/search/pop">PopStation</a> 


In this case I want to highligh POP keyword but it also takes in consideration the pop keyword in anchor tag which I dont want. It should only take the text value for highlighting purpose.

Comment: @pramodg Can you then edit your question, providing detailed explanation of what you want, and probably a few examples. Otherwise people are trying to guess what you are trying to do, and it doesn't help anybody.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can try to use something that is called "negative lookbehind" and "negative lookahead"

Basically what you are trying to say is "I want to match the string 'pop' but not if it is within symbols '<' and '>'".

This can be realised in the following manner:

```
/(?<!<[^>]*)$needle(?![^<]*>)/
```

Let's take this apart:

- `(?<` means a lookbehind. This causes a test to be done before the matched string.
- `!` negates this lookbehind. This causes the positive test to become negative and vice versa.
- `<[^>]*` find an the beginning of the tag, that doesn't have an ending. So "" or "a " will not.
- `(?` means a lookahead. Similar to lookabehind, but after the string.
- `!` negates.
- `[^<]*>` ending of the tag, without opening of one.